# Meteor Accounts-UI-Bootstrap - Popups don't close

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

I'm learning javascript & Meteor and trying out the bootstrap accounts package https://github.com/ianmartorell/meteor-accounts-ui-bootstrap-3/

If I attempt oauth with google, facebook, or twitter I get the popup window verifying access for the app from the respective services ( so I assume the setup on the services and callback url is correct ). Once I ok access, the popup window is blank, and doesn't close.

I'm running on localhost for testing, if that makes a difference.

Where would I start debugging this issue?

Comment: If you had inspected the popup window and looked at the output in the console you had seen a SecurityError dialog. that is one way to start debugging this.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably having problems with the ROOT_URL setting. It needs to match the the domain AND protocol the user is seeing. That means you can initiate logins from http://yoursite.com OR https://yoursite.com, but since the ROOT_URL setting needs to match the site and protocol/port, you have to choose either one and redirect users to the right one before initiating a login.

Usually this is not a problem when developing locally as Meteor deals with this automatically ... are you sure you are supplying all info here? This problem usually only comes up when you have deployed the app somewhere, perhaps behind a web proxy and Meteor is unable to get the ports right.

- [This meteor-talk discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/meteor-talk/Im8jL8lxyu4) has lots of relevant info regarding this.
- Official docs on [Meteor.absoluteUrl](https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_absoluteurl)

Comment: Thank-you very much for this. The ROOT_URL is set correctly ( protocol+url) in an upstart file. I was testing on a windows 7 box & deploying to Ubuntu digital ocean server. For some reason, the window not closing behavior went away when I just did everything on Ubuntu. However, now a different issue surfaced, so I've opened another question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31351030/oauth-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-1-of-null