# Oauth / Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

I'm trying out meteor oauth using google-accounts. I'm seeing it working fine locally, but when I deploy ( using this process http://bit.ly/1Hrp7Oz ), no oauth popup appears and I see this error:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null 
which is occurring at line 3 packages/url/url_client.js

```
    URL._constructUrl = function (url, query, params) {  
    var query_match = /^(.*?)(\?.*)?$/.exec(url); 
    Url(query_match[1], query_match[2], query, params);                  // 3
  };
```

Not sure how to debug this

Comment: I should add ROOT_URL is set in the upstart file to the correct url  and https protocol.

Comment: looks like query_match is coming back null, but I can't figure out what would cause it to do that.  try inserting console.log(url); after the start of the function and see the value of url.

Answer (score 0):

with jbangerter's help, found it... I had been doing some initial development on win7, and that included editing one of the upstart configuration files. That embedded a cr/lf at the end of the setting for ROOT_URL. Meteor was not stripping the cr/lf from the ROOT_URL variable so it wound up being used by the google oauth library.